# c# async file extension check with action filter ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: c#, actionfilterattribute

The idea behind is that I have an ActionFilterAttribute who is checking the file extension. If the file extension exist it can pass otherwise throw an error. I have multiple fileuploads on diffrent places.

I have a singlepage application running where user can upload files. It runs on javascript knockout.js and c#.

The problem is that I get always Count = 0 in the MultipartMemoryStreamProvider

Here is the code who is calling the ActionFilterAttribute on the first line

```
[DocumentUploadValidationAttribute]
    [HttpPost, Route("documents/upload/{customerId}/{documentType}")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadCustomerDocument(int customerId, string documentType)
    {
        try
        {
            await data.Document.UploadCustomerDocument(Request, customerId, documentType);
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The ActionFilterAttribute looks like this. In the foreach loop provider.Content is 0 but why?

```
namespace VZ.VMS.UI.Validation {
public class DocumentUploadValidationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
        var task = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

        foreach (var file in provider.Contents)
        {
            var filename = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('\"');
            var extension = Path.GetExtension(filename).Replace(".", "");

            if (extension != "pdf" && extension != "docx" && extension != "xlsx" && extension != "img" && extension != "png")
            {
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new { errorMessage = "error_code" }, actionContext.ControllerContext.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should await the result of the method ReadAsMultipartAsync(), like `actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).Wait()`

Comment: Thanks Jehof for the tip but now it comes this error message
The name 'Wait' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Have you write it as follows? 
var task = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
task.Wait();

Comment: yes but after task.Wait() nothing happens. the testfilesize is arround 0.7mb